# How can I create a loop statement in BigQuery and add difference in days since the start-records for each record in the same loop?

Tags: select, while-loop, google-bigquery

I want to create a table with a select statement, that for each record where "Type = Start" takes all the records that have the same "Domain" as the Start-record AND have a timestamp that is the same as the Start-record or up to Two years after.

Also if there is another Start-record in this period that also have the same Domain. In those cases the same record can be added multiple times.

I also want to add a field "Days" that contain the number of days since the Start-record.

I want an additional id "New_Id" that has the same id as the original Start-record for all the records in the Start/domain/two-years-range.

I have a table:

| Id | Domain | Type | Timestamp | coll1 | coll2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 400 | domain3 | **Start** | 2021-05-20T09:26:49 | content | content |
| 5 | domain2 | Other | 2021-02-14T12:16:32 | content | content |
| 100 | domain1 | **Start** | 2021-04-13T03:23:11 | content | content |
| 4 | domain2 | Other | 2021-02-14T12:16:32 | content | content |
| 5 | domain2 | Other | 2021-05-10T13:16:35 | content | content |
| 200 | domain2 | **Start** | 2021-04-19T07:10:08 | content | content |
| 7 | domain3 | Other | 2021-06-17T10:30:40 | content | content |
| 8 | domain3 | Other | 2021-05-14T12:47:42 | content | content |
| 1 | domain1 | Other | 2021-05-17T09:26:45 | content | content |
| 3 | domain1 | Other | 2021-04-13T03:23:11 | content | content |
| 3 | domain1 | Other | 2021-06-13T16:56:51 | content | content |
| 2 | domain1 | Other | 2021-05-20T09:26:49 | content | content |
| 3 | domain1 | Other | 2021-05-01T13:17:31 | content | content |
| 9 | domain3 | Other | 2021-06-13T16:56:51 | content | content |
| 7 | domain3 | Other | 2021-06-17T10:30:40 | content | content |
| 7 | domain3 | Other | 2021-05-10T13:16:35 | content | content |
| 5 | domain2 | Other | 2021-04-19T07:10:08 | content | content |
| 1 | domain1 | Other | 2021-05-14T12:47:42 | content | content |
| 300 | domain3 | **Start** | 2021-05-13T08:40:04 | content | content |
| 8 | domain3 | Other | 2021-05-17T09:26:45 | content | content |
| 5 | domain2 | Other | 2021-05-01T13:17:31 | content | content |

And I want to end with a new table like this:

| New_Id | Id | Domain | Type | Timestamp | Days | coll1 | coll2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 100 | domain1 | **Start** | 2021-04-13T03:23:11 | 0 | content | content |
| 100 | 3 | domain1 | Other | 2021-05-01T13:17:31 | 18 | content | content |
| 100 | 1 | domain1 | Other | 2021-05-14T12:47:42 | 31 | content | content |
| 100 | 1 | domain1 | Other | 2021-05-17T09:26:45 | 34 | content | content |
| 100 | 2 | domain1 | Other | 2021-05-20T09:26:49 | 37 | content | content |
| 100 | 3 | domain1 | Other | 2021-06-13T16:56:51 | 61 | content | content |
| 200 | 200 | domain2 | **Start** | 2021-04-19T07:10:08 | 0 | content | content |
| 200 | 5 | domain2 | Other | 2021-04-19T07:10:08 | 0 | content | content |
| 200 | 5 | domain2 | Other | 2021-05-01T13:17:31 | 12 | content | content |
| 200 | 5 | domain2 | Other | 2021-05-10T13:16:35 | 21 | content | content |
| 300 | 300 | domain3 | **Start** | 2021-05-13T08:40:04 | 0 | content | content |
| 300 | 8 | domain3 | Other | 2021-05-14T12:47:42 | 1 | content | content |
| 300 | 8 | domain3 | Other | 2021-05-17T09:26:45 | 4 | content | content |
| 300 | 9 | domain3 | Other | 2021-06-13T16:56:51 | 31 | content | content |
| 300 | 7 | domain3 | Other | 2021-06-17T10:30:40 | 35 | content | content |
| 300 | 7 | domain3 | Other | 2021-06-17T10:30:40 | 35 | content | content |
| 400 | 400 | domain3 | **Start** | 2021-05-20T09:26:49 | 0 | content | content |
| 400 | 9 | domain3 | Other | 2021-06-13T16:56:51 | 24 | content | content |
| 400 | 7 | domain3 | Other | 2021-06-17T10:30:40 | 28 | content | content |
| 400 | 7 | domain3 | Other | 2021-06-17T10:30:40 | 28 | content | content |

Comment: what you tried so far? what the issue you are facing?

Comment: I have tried some nested WHILE statements, but can't seem to even get a simple version to work. I thought something like the lines of: 
WHILE Type IN ('Start*) DO
SELECT id as New_Id,
    WHILE Domain IN ('Start-record-domain*) DO
    SELECT 
      id as id,
      domain as domain,
     type as type,
     timestamp as timestamp,
     start-timestimp minus timestamp as days,
    coll1 as coll1,
    coll2 as coll2,
  FROM table1
 END WHILE;
END WHILE;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below approach (note use of [recently introduced](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes?hl=en_US#May_10_2021) in Preview - [QUALIFY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause) clause)

```
select first_row.id as new_id, 
  id, domain, type, timestamp, 
  timestamp_diff(timestamp, first_row.timestamp, day) as days, 
  coll1, coll2
from (
  select *, 
    first_value(t) over(partition by domain, grp order by timestamp) first_row
  from (
    select *, 
      countif(type = 'Start') over(partition by domain order by timestamp) grp
    from `project.dataset.table`
  ) t
  where grp > 0 
  qualify timestamp_diff(timestamp, first_row.timestamp, day) < 2 * 365
) 
-- order by domain, timestamp
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

UPDATE: in my initial answer above I've missed this part of OP's requirements: *Also if there is another Start-record in this period that also have the same Domain. In those cases the same record can be added multiple times*.
Below answer addresses all OP's requirements

```
with starts as (
  select * from `project.dataset.table` where type = 'Start'
), others as (
  select * from `project.dataset.table` where type != 'Start'
)
select s.id as new_id, o.id, o.domain, o.type, o.timestamp, 
  timestamp_diff(o.timestamp, s.timestamp, day) as days, 
  o.coll1, o.coll2
from others o 
join starts s 
on s.domain = o.domain 
and o.timestamp >= s.timestamp
and timestamp_diff(o.timestamp, s.timestamp, day) < 2 * 365
union all 
select id as new_id, id, domain, type, timestamp, 0 as days, coll1, coll2
from starts
-- order by domain, new_id, timestamp
```

If applied to sample data in the question - output is

[image]

Comment: This almost get it, but still don't add all records in the same domain two years back from each Start-Type. If so, the Other-records from Start-Type 400 would also be in Start-type 300. How can I get all the records from same domain added to multiple Start-Types, if several of them are older than the Start-Type timestamp?

Comment: Wouldn't it need some kind of loop or while, since it may have to "use" the same records several times, for different Start-types with the same domain?

Comment: looks like I've missed this part of your requirements: **Also if there is another Start-record in this period that also have the same Domain. In those cases the same record can be added multiple times.** Will take a look again later in a day

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.